# asyncAfter with no time seems delay - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Eventually I have used asyncAfter feature in swift with no time, and it does some delay and seems different with normal code.

Code with async:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0 , execute: {
    self.updateUI()
})
```

Normal code:

```
self.updateUI()
```

Similar problem with perform selector also.

```
self.performSelector("onFlip", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0)
```

Is that delay is caused because of creating new thread?

Comment: Probably does the same thing that “async” would do - schedule block on next runloop.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0 , execute: {
    self.updateUI()
})
```

Is essentially the same as

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.updateUI()
}
```

which also won't execute immediately due to the fact that you dispatch the code to the main thread **asynchronously**. Due to the async dispatch, the code inside the closure won't be executed immediately, only on the next runloop of main, which might result in a measurable delay .

Comment: Thanks. what you meant by next runloop?

Comment: @Saranjith [RunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) from the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

`asyncAfter` doesn't create a new thread, since you are dispatching on the main queue, which will use the main thread, but neither will it execute the dispatched code immediately.

You have submitted a block of code to run on the main queue, so some time will elapse before the runloop can execute that code; particularly if the `asyncAfter` is being called on the main thread.